# GC collects referenced object after return from scope

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a question about how GC works in Java.
Consider the following code:

```
class C1 {
    ArrayList<int> myList = new ArrayList<int>();

    public void setList(ArrayList<int> l) {
         myList = l;
    }
}

func(C1 C) {
    ArrayList<int> l1 = new ArrayList<int>();
    l1.add(1);
    C.setList(l1);
}

main() {
    C1 C = new C1();
    func(C);
    ...
}
```

my question is:
does GC releases 'l1' after `func()` returns or not?

Comment: Is your question about after `main()` ends, or are you envisioning other activity in `main()` that is strictly unrelated to `C`?

Comment: no, consider other activities in `main()` unrelated to C.

Comment: For reference, `ArrayList<int>` isn't a thing that compiles.  `ArrayList<Integer>` might, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't, because there's a root reference (stack variable `C`) which has a strong reference (`myList`), to the new `ArrayList`. After `main()` returns, then the `C1` and the `ArrayList` are collectible, because the root reference disappears.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an optimization that HotSpot's JIT does, which is detecting the point at which a local var will no longer be accessed and clearing it at that moment. So the full answer to your question is "it might, but there is no guarantee". Recently I played with some code and measured the memory taken by a large array. Until I actually inserted `array.hashCode()` at te end of the method, I observed it was being released earlier.